# Enunciate Documentation - Ignore on a specific field not working

Tags: enunciate

I'm trying to generate enunciate documentation (version 2.3.0). As per the documentation to ignore a specific field on the response sample, we could use either on the following. I have tried using them, but still the documentation creates a sample Json with that field.

```
@JsonIgnore -- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
@Ignore -- com.webcohesion.enunciate.metadata.Ignore
```

I have tried with all the combinations with these 2 different types of Ignore.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enunciate ignores fields by using `@JsonIgnore` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnorecom.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` on the getter of the field

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was searching for... I tested `@Ignore`, `@JsonIgnore` and `@XMLTransient`.
All are working, but only on the getter method.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ignore documentation of Enunciate](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Enunciate-Specific-Annotations):

> Applied to a Java class

So I don't thing you will find any annotation that suits your needs.

I my projects I use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) which generate getter and setter automatically. Enunciate does not support lombok yet (but there is an issue about that so it may be supported in a near future).

You can simply use lombok to generate the getter/setter. They will be hidden from enunciate.

It's more a tricks than a real solution but it could help.

Comment: I have seen this examples already. What you understood is to exclude a file all together. My question was just a field inside a file.